# Can't choose a different site on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm trying to choose some of my top answers from Programmers.SE to display in my Careers 2.0 profile.  <strike>Nothing happens when I click on the dropdown menu.</strike>  The HTML seems to be well-formatted.  What's up?

EDIT: When I click on the edges, it works fine.  Otherwise, I am left with something that should be clickable but doesn't react.

- Browser: Google Chrome 23
- OS: Linux Mint 13

As a sidenote, could the options only contain sites I added?

Comment: Browser? Browser Version? Operating System?

Comment: @AndyDwyer Apologies for forgetting that.  Added.

Comment: @AndyDwyer Weekday when you tried it? `;)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting CSS issue here... This is actually caused by the select menu being floated to the right. Since the header-level-3 element has a `position: relative` applied to it, z-index takes precedence and pushes it on top of the floated content, so the select element is being shown *behind* it in the page layout. Therefore, there is a sort of "bar" that goes through the box where you're actually hovering over the header element and *not* the select element.

> [image: View from element inspector]

This should apply to *all* browsers and is not specific to Chrome. Removing the `position: relative` from the header element, or adding it to the select element along with a high z-index, solves this issue.

Comment: Just fixed this, it's going live within the next few hours.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is now fixed with a small CSS update.